Custom product type - add Product to WooCommerce Cart
I am trying to add my product to cart.
I have created product type bookable_product. So when I executed below code
function add_bookable_product_to_cart()
{
   if (! is_admin()) {
      $product_id = 38; // Your bookable product ID
      $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id($product_id);

      if (! WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart($product_cart_id)) {
         // Add the bookable product to the cart
         $added = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);

         if (!$added) {
            // Handle failure to add, maybe log or display an error
            error_log('Could not add product to cart: ' . $product_id);
         }
      }
   }
}
add_action("wp", "add_bookable_product_to_cart", 10);

As per this doc
I have used WooCommerce for only product management purpose all fields I have created my self. So in default product I have not added any data of WC.

I have not created any variation I have created 1 custom product type and removed all tabs
And I have taken custom product data like ticket name price and qty in this new tab in add more function
So now on frontend I Have shown all custom fields and when clicked on button I want to add this to cart

Since you dont have any wc product data how to validate your "product"? Maybe start from here woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation. wp is wrong hook to be used. Also you need to provide your price qty and other data in your cart item woocommerce_add_cart_item_data. If you want to show any cart item data use this woocommerce_get_item_data. Then you need to calculate your order at checkout woocommerce_before_calculate_totals.
